# How to use join query for displaying data from multiple tables in greenDAO?

Tags: android, greendao

Following is my DAOgenerator class:

```
public class MyDaoGenerator {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Schema schema = new Schema(3, "Dao");

        Entity employee = schema.addEntity("Employee");
        employee.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
        employee.addStringProperty("name");
        employee.addStringProperty("mobile");
        employee.addStringProperty("address");
        employee.addStringProperty("company_id");

        Entity company = schema.addEntity("Company");
        company.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
        company.addStringProperty("comp_name");
        company.addStringProperty("comp_location");
        company.addStringProperty("comp_address");



        new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, args[0]);
    }
}
```

Following is my DAO queries class.
This class has all the function like `insert`, `delete`, `clear table`:

```
public class DaoQueries {

    private static CompanyDao getMyCompanyDao(Context context){
        return ((AppMain)context.getApplicationContext()).getDaoSession().getCompanyDao();
    }


    public static void AddCompany(Context context,Company company){
        getMyCompanyDao(context).insertOrReplace(company);
    }

    public static int companySize(Context context){
        return  getMyCompanyDao(context).loadAll().size();
    }    

    public static List<Company> getCompanies(Context context){
        return getMyCompanyDao(context).loadAll();
    }

    private static EmployeeDao getEmployeeDao(Context context){
        return ((AppMain)context.getApplicationContext()).getDaoSession().getEmployeeDao();
    }
    public static void AddEmployee(Context context,Employee employee){
        getEmployeeDao(context).insertOrReplace(employee);
    }    


    public static List<Employee> getEmployees(Context context){
        return getEmployeeDao(context).loadAll();
    }

    public static void joinedUser(Context context){

        QueryBuilder<Employee> queryBuilder = getEmployeeDao(context).queryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.join(Company.class,CompanyDao.Properties.Id)
            .where(CompanyDao.Properties.Id.eq(1));

        List<Employee> employees = queryBuilder.list();
        Log.e("DAO","EMPLOYE JOIN "+employees.size());

    }
}
```

I tried join query with greenDAO as mentioned in dao documentation for getting rows from both the tables like this:

```
public static void joinedUser(Context context){

    QueryBuilder<Employee> queryBuilder = getEmployeeDao(context).queryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.join(Company.class,CompanyDao.Properties.Id)
            .where(CompanyDao.Properties.Id.eq(1));

    List<Employee> employees = queryBuilder.list();
    Log.e("DAO","EMPLOYE JOIN "+employees.size());

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? `employes` is being loaded? There is some error?

Comment: the query is wrong,i want to display in my recyclerview data from both the tables like company_name,company_address by joining Employee table with Company table where emppoy table companyId == Company Table id.Please help me with join query. thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show data from both tables, you can use greenDAO relations. In your case, you will need a 1:1 relation between `Employee` and `Company`. So, greenDAO will create a `Employee` class with a member of type `Company` and when you load a `Employee`, greenDAO will perform the join query and load the related company.

The new generator code:

```
public class MyDaoGenerator {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Schema schema = new Schema(3, "Dao");
        Entity company = schema.addEntity("Company");
        company.addIdProperty().autoincrement().notNull();
        company.addStringProperty("comp_name");
        company.addStringProperty("comp_location");
        company.addStringProperty("comp_address");


        Entity employee = schema.addEntity("Employee");
        employee.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
        employee.addStringProperty("name");
        employee.addStringProperty("mobile");
        employee.addStringProperty("address");
        Property companyId = employee.addLongProperty("company_id").getProperty();
        employee.addToOne(company, companyId);

        new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, args[0]);
    }

}
```

Getting the employees of company with `company_id = 1`:

```
QueryBuilder<Employee> queryBuilder = getEmployeeDao(context).queryBuilder();
List<Employee> employees = qb.where(EmployeeDao.Properties.Company_id.eq(1)).list();
```

Iterating through employees:

```
foreach(Employee employee : employees){
    Company company = employee.getCompany();
    String companyAddress = company.getComp_address(); 
    //...
}
```

For more info, check [greeenDAO Relations Docs](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/relations/).

Comment: How can i get rows from 2 tables in one list and return like we usually do in greendao for single table

Comment: @DhanrajNaik This is what my answer does: get rows from two tables and return in one list.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to get all the rows from both the tables and display in recyclerview.
using join query ,i want company details from Company table as currently i was fetching all the data from Employee table as a list and Employee table has no Company details .

Comment: cant i return columns from both the tables using join query in a single list ?
like
public static List<EmployeeAndCompanyDetail> getEmployees(Context context){
        return getEmployeeDao(context).loadAll();
    }

Comment: In my answer, you already has company details for every employee: `Company company = employee.getCompany();`. I updated the answer for more clarification.